# Leaflet - jQuery - Cannot see the circle on the map - "TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function"

Tags: jquery, leaflet

It's the first time I use LeafLet and I have an error I do not understand.

This is my code first :
`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var map_announce = null;

    if (positionType == "zipcode" || positionType == "city") {
        jQuery(".appt-desc__map-no-position").show();
        map_announce = new mapClass('appt-desc__div-map', zoom, {lat: 46.5, lng: 2.6067229}, [post_data], customCircle_announce);
        map_announce.changeView(city, null, zoom);
    } else if (positionType == "gps") {
        zoom = 16;
        jQuery(".appt-desc__map-no-position").hide();
        if(document.getElementById('appt-desc__div-map')){
            map_announce = new mapClass('appt-desc__div-map', zoom, {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, [post_data]);
            map_announce.changeView(null, {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}, zoom);
            var customCircle_announce = L.circle([post_data.lat, post_data.lng], {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                radius: 500
            }).addTo(map_announce);
        }
    }    
});
```

As you can see, new mapClass creates the map with zoom, and gps coordinates. But when I add the circle I have this error on the picture -> t.addLayer is not a function, I don't understand, because when I use an icon it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eQjQ.png)

I'm just trying first to have a circle on the map but it does not appear, I have this marker instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU29S.png)

Thanks for your help.

I'm expecting to have this kind of result. I just want the circle appears on the map.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSZSf.png)

Comment: move your `var map_announce = null;` outside the jquery function, would be my guess

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be `null` - You can just set it like `var map;`